# When and when not borders are necessary? ( iOS design)

Tags: interface-design, design-principles, mobile, borders

I'm trying to understand, if the usage of a **border at the navigation bar** contribute to the design/UX in some way? Would love to hear your thoughts about that.

**Designed for iOS**

[image]

Comment: Can we start from a point of your thoughts?

Comment: Hey @Confused, thank you for responding. Well, basically i'm trying to understand - In case we don't have a border, will it cause the user who's using the app, to "blend" between parts of the interface? or the border is needed to avoid the "blend" effect.. I'm seriously lost (i'm not a designer, actually i'm the developer, and it's just a design i came up with)

Comment: Just in case it didn't tagged you - @Confused

Answer (score 0):

For reasons not pertinent to design, the simplest answer is to follow Apple's guidelines, which give you two choices, neither of which is a line as a border:

1. use a different colour for the navigation bar or
2. blend it as in your first example, without a border or colour differentiation, and rely on the intelligence of your users and the obvious context the content of the navigation bar provides.